# Nginx Redirection Issue

Tags: nginx, wordpress

My Nginx setting currently has this:

```
 location / {
       if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://domain.com/index.php?id=$1 redirect;
       }
 }
```

Basically for non-existing pages (404) it redirects user to the home page. But now I have a wordpress blog setup at https://domain.com/blog/, but any wordpress items eg. https://domain.com/blog/test also got redirected to the home page. I wonder how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If your blog is at `http://yourblog.com/blog`, then you need to set the directive to that path, unless you've previously specified that as your `root` directory (e.g. `root /var/www/html/blog`).

You should also **NOT** be using `if` statements. [It's a common NGiNX pitfall.](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/). Use [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/r/try_files) instead.

```
location /blog {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

If you don't want sub-directories of `/blog` to be redirected, you can limit the redirect to just that specific directory by using the `=` in the location directive.

E.g.

```
location = /blog {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

If you want it to search for *anything* that says "blog", and apply that same redirect, you would use a `/` before *and* after, so that it uses it as a regular expression.

E.g.

```
location /blog/ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

More information on the location directive can be found [HERE](http://nginx.org/r/location).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437613/nginx-location-directive-matching-order) and the documentation for `location` [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location):

> there is no syntax for NOT matching a regular expression. Instead, match the target regular expression and assign an empty block, then use location / to match anything else.

I would say that you need to have a location directive that matches `/blog/` and with an empty block to prevent the redirection, something like

```
location /blog {
}
```

Comment: There should not be a trailing slash after `blog`.